# Failed to resolve volley library

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to use RequestQeue for basic HTTP connection and I know that this question is asked many times but none of the solutions that is suggested does not work for me. I have searched through the every single answer but it did not help. Here is my project and module gradle in the below. I would be appreciated if someone give me a tip; This is the error message : Failed to resolve:com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pc.wampproj"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
}
```

The module;
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Please show the entire error message.

Comment: What questions did you find? What exactly did you try? What happened?

Comment: I tried to add compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0' to the dependencies and it demonsrated that it failed to resolve :compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0' @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Basically, everybody suggested only this solution and to keep jcenter in reposotories. I did both, still get the error. @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Besides, I also receive the same error when I use  compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19' too @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Please edit your question to show that.

Comment: What you are doing looks correct to me. Are there any problems with your internet connection?

Comment: I edited it, my internet works like a charm @Code-Apprentice

Comment: I meant the com.android.volley since this is the one you should use. Try starting a new, empty Android Studio project and see what happens when you add the volley dependency.

Comment: I reseted my internet connection and somehow it worked. I would not think about it without your help, thanks @Code-Apprentice